# In C varargs, is it possible to send args of different type

Tags: c

In the function which receives arguments of various type, i have used varargs, 
and i am decoding all the arguments to one type as below

```
va_start (ap, argCount);
for (u4Index = 0; u4Index < argCount; u4Index++)
{    
    ai4Arg[u4Index] = va_arg (ap, int);
}    
va_end (ap);

switch (Opt)
{    
    case 1:
        func1((int) ai4Arg[0],
                (int *) ai4Arg[1]);
        break;

    case 2:
         func2((char *) ai4Arg[0],
                (int *) ai4Arg[1]);
        break;
 }
```

and then i am typecasting the arguments to the respective types. Doing so while trying to typecast an argument from INT4 to a pointer, i am getting the below warning
"cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]".
Is above the right to way to use varargs.

Comment: partially yes, you can pass different types, just for example if first N arguments are of same type, and all next arguments are of another type. you need to know the ordering of types, to retrieve them correctly

Comment: or you're asking about the case, when you pass all same type, and you just want to see them differently inside of a function, based on some `Opt`?

Comment: seems a bit odd that you on one hand allow variable number of arguments but then you anyway know what the argument types are - it sort of defeats the purpose somewhat and makes the code more difficult to maintain and error handling will be rough.

Comment: use first parameter of you function to distinguish va_arg types, the same way printf() family do

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not the correct way to use varargs.

The type you pass to va_arg must be the argument's actual type. You can't pick a random type, and then cast it later.

That said, there is a good chance that your current code will work *on some platforms*. It might not work on other compilers. It definitely won't work on 64-bit Windows, because `int` is 32 bits and pointers are 64 bits - so why not do it the right way instead?

Edit:

You should only call va_arg *after* you know the type. For example:

```
va_start (ap, argCount);
switch (Opt)
{    
case 1: {
    int intParam = va_arg(ap, int);
    int *intPtrParam = va_arg(ap, int*);
    func1(intParam, intPtrParam);
    break;

case 2:
    char *charPtrParam = va_arg(ap, char*);
    intPtrParam = va_arg(ap, int*);
    func2(charPtrParam, intPtrParam);
    break;
}
va_end(ap);
```

Comment: if i used pointer to decode the arguments va_arg(ap, int*);
and while typecasting if i did it in the below, its working fine for me, i am not getting any warnings  (char) (long) ai4Arg[0]                Is the correct way ?

Comment: No. The correct way is to give va_arg the *correct type*. It might work on your system, but it's an unnecessary risk that you might compile it for something else later, forget to fix this code, and get hacked.